# Share an image with only a few specified apps in Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentprovider, cross-application

I've got three Apps A, B and C. App A captures an image and sends it to B which then sends it to C. App A and B are developed by me and C is not.
Currently I'm sending the images with intents but those can only send 1mb max.(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html)

If I want to use a Content Provider, app C will not have the same signature as A and B, but the content of the image is very sensitive and can not be leaked. Therefore the Content Provider has to be set to android:exported="true".
If I understand it correctly, the user has to decide if an app can access contents with a ContentProvider using Permissions, so this is not a safe solution.

Another approach might be to segment the data and send it to the other apps using a Service (which can only send 1mb max, too), but this is difficult, I guess.

Is there a safe solution for this problem, that I am missing?

Comment: You could perhaps encrypt the images. However, doing encryption right is hard. You have to share a key between the apps, and all apps involved have to keep the keys safe.

Comment: Could you serialise your big image and send it time to time instead of sending it one time? I mean using pub/sub pattern to push/pull parts of image.

Comment: *If I understand it correctly..., so this is not a safe solution*  .... you didn't .. it's up to you to use  `Context.grantUriPermission` ... so it's pretty safe